# How to fix Nav Item Position and Dropdown Position?

Tags: html, css, navigation, bootstrap-5

So i have been working with bootstrap dropdowns and its not aligning correctly for some reason. I tried using multiple solutions such as updating my bootstrap versions but they aren't working at all.

Here is my code:

```html
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://css.gg/add.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/dashboard.css">
</head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/img/AdiAvi.png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="/static/js/dashboard.js"></script>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/dashboard.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/base.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Avyukt&#39;s Dashboard</title>
    
    <style>
      .trigger {
        display: none !important;
      }
      #loginButton {
        display: none !important;
      }
    </style>
    
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <img class="ms-3" src="/static/img/AdiAvi.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
      AdiAvi
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 align-items-start align-items-lg-center">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a   class="nav-link active"  class="nav-link"  href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a  class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        
        
        
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <img src="/static/profilePictures/A.png" width="50" height="50" class="rounded-circle mt-8">
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/account">Edit Profile</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Log Out</a>
          </div>
        </li>
           
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I am using bootstrap 5 and i think i am using the latest versions of the bundle.

Screenshot: https://ibb.co/pQPVdx2

Like i cant even click on the dropdown.

Comment: Alright im fixing it right now

Comment: Edit: I fixed it, the image holders a little wacky, but it does the job.

Comment: You are using the wrong bootstrap.js version it should match the bootstrap.css version, significant changes have been made between the two you are using and could result in unpredictable behavior, and missing functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your code to use the proper version of the bootstrap.js & popper.js (or use the bootstrap.bundle.js). **You will then need to modify all of your Bootstrap-specific `data-*` attribute names to use the new format for BS5+: `data-bs-*`.**
Your issue with the [dropdown menu alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment) is solved by adding `.dropdown-menu-end` to the `.dropdown-menu`.
The vertical [alignment of the `.nav-item`s](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#align-items) can be controlled by adding a `.align-items-*` class to the parent `.navbar-nav`. **Be aware**, this also affects the horizontal alignment on the mobile collapsed navbar. Use the responsive variant (`.align-items-lg-center`) matching the breakpoint of your navbar (`.navbar-expand-lg`) to control alignment only for the expanded state.

Here is a minimal example with `.nav-item`s having left alignment for collapsed navbar, and vertically centered for expanded navbar:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-black">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
    <img class="ms-3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/30" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""> AdiAvi
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 align-items-start align-items-lg-center">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" width="50" height="50" class="rounded-circle mt-8">
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/account">Edit Profile</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Log Out</a>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

### Note:

As is the above snippet and in the docs, the bootstrap.js should be included at the end just before the closing body tag.

> Include Bootstrap’s CSS and JS. Place the `<link>` tag in the `<head>` for our CSS, and the `<script>` tag for our JavaScript bundle (including Popper for positioning dropdowns, poppers, and tooltips) before the closing `</body>`.
>
> --https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start

Comment: Here i edited my answer, but this time i can't even click on the dropdown itself

Comment: You did not replace the data attribute names for the ` .navbar-toggler`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR FIXING THE PROBLEM! I thought it had something to do with bootstrap, but after i read your note thing i realized i put the script in the wrong location, but after i put it in the correct location it started working! TYSM!